# Xamarin.Forms compilation warnings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After updating some Xamarin NuGet package libraries in my Xamarin.Forms project (Android only), I'm getting a lot of warnings, but everything seems to work fine.

I have these packages installed in my project:

- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2622
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.8.1
- Xamarin.CommunityToolkit 2.0.6

Any idea on how to get rid of these?

```
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.TESTS
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.TESTS
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.TESTS
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
...
JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
```

Comment: I found the related issue about the [New bunch of warnings using Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotations 1.6.0](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/727#issuecomment-1538487696). You can check this issue.

Comment: Thank you @GuangyuBai-MSFT, do you think it's safe for the future of the project to update only the NuGet package "Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation", even if it is a transitive package? (I have it at version 1.6.0.1 at the moment, never updated manually)

Comment: Yes, it is safe to update it to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Guangyu Bai comment, I manually updated the NuGet transitive package **Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation** to version 1.7.0.3 (from version 1.6.0.1: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3).

I recompiled the whole solution in every configuration and all the warnings went away.